# What does each Eternal's suit iconography show?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, eternals-2021

Each Eternal's suit is unique, but each seems to have some iconography at the top of the chest. Ikaris' suit seems to show a stylised person with wings, but I could be imagining it.

What are the designs on each suit and what if anything are they trying to tell us about the characters?

[image: Ikaris]

[image: Sprite]

[image: Phastos]

[image: Makkari]

[image: Druig]

[image: Thena]

[image: Sersi]

[image: Kingo]

[image: Gilgamesh]

[image: Ajax]

Comment: Look it's Super [Cueball](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/Cueball)!  (That really does look more like a cape than wings.  Maybe it's Super Stan.)

Comment: https://hollywoodmoviecostumesandprops.blogspot.com/2022/01/eternals-movie-costumes-on-display.html - The costume icons seems to be largely meaningless, with occasional bits that aren't.(like a pair of scissors)

Comment: "*For example, Zhao wanted the costumes to have a shared language through symbology and insignias, in addition to incorporating the cuneiform language embedded in the design of the bridge in the Domo, the Eternals’ ship. “The language was not an A, B, C,” Sheldon Differ says. “They represented ‘water,’ ‘God,’ ‘heaven’ and ‘love’—those kinds of things. Each symbol represents something elemental.”*" -https://thewaltdisneycompany.com/threading-the-eternals-history-into-their-mcu-costumes/

Comment: The Kingo one looks like it incorporates Ikaris' design, identifying his similar (lower level) powerset and hinting at the final showdown positions?